# Visual force apex:vote component doesn't rerender the area

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, knowledge, rerender

I've encountered with a bit strange behaviour related to apex:vote visual force component.

According to the official documentation this component has 'rerender' attribute (as basically many others). The problem is that for some reason it doesn't wanna trigger rerendering of the area at all.

The interesting thing is that if I replace this component with some dummy commandButton and try to rerender exactly the same area by on-click event from exactly the same place it works successfully.

So looks like it's not the problems with the area, invalid id, some non-rendered panels etc. Looks like it's the component itself.
I read that 'rerender' attribute is available in api version 33 and higher, my api version is 34.

Any ideas from the community side would be appreciated.
And thanks in advance for your help.

Below is the piece of page:

```
<apex:pageBlock title="{!FAQ__kav.Title}" id="mainBlock">

    <apex:form >

        <apex:outputpanel id="rating">

            <apex:vote objectId="{!FAQ__kav.KnowledgeArticleId}" rerender="rating" />

            <apex:outputText value="Average Rating: "/>
            <apex:outputText value="{0, number, 0.00}">
                <apex:param value="{!Rate}"/>
            </apex:outputText>

            <br></br><br></br>

            <apex:commandLink value="Save as pdf" action="{!setContentTypePDF}"/>

        </apex:outputpanel>

    </apex:form>

</apex:pageBlock>
```